# Errors when filling/replacing NoData values with Raster Calculator FocalStatistics

Tags: arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, error-000539, focal-statistics

I have the following raster, which has many NoData values. Only the NoData values that are in the ocean need to be filled.
[image]

I made a seperate raster with all the NoData cells that are in the ocean. I am trying to apply this method: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000004792 to fill them.
[image]

To do this, I wrote the following code in the Raster Calculator:

```
Con(IsNull("%GapsToFill%"), FocalStatistics("%OceanSalinity%", NbrRectangle(10,10, "CELL"), "MEAN"), "%OceanSalinity%")
```

However, I keep getting the following error message. Does anyone know why this error occurs?

```
ERROR 000539: Error running expression: rcexec() 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<expression>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 5, in rcexec
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.6\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 5375, in FocalStatistics
    ignore_nodata)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.6\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Utils.py", line 53, in swapper
    result = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.6\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 5369, in Wrapper
    ignore_nodata)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.6\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 510, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
ExecuteError: ERROR 000875: Output raster: Z:\WUR\GasDrive_Thesis\ArcGIS\Application\IA_GasDrive_Step.gdb\FocalSt_ps_a2_S1.tif's workspace is an invalid output workspace.
ERROR 000581: Invalid parameters.
Failed to execute (FocalStatistics).


Failed to execute (Raster Calculator (2)).
```

I also tried to skip the GapsToFill raster and just use the following code, which gives exactly the same error message

```
Con(IsNull("%OceanSalinity%"), FocalStatistics("%OceanSalinity%", NbrRectangle(10,10, "CELL"), "MEAN"), "%OceanSalinity%")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write a geotiff to a file geodatabase.

Change your output raster to either:

- a file geodatabase raster

  ```
  Z:\WUR\GasDrive_Thesis\ArcGIS\Application\IA_GasDrive_Step.gdb\FocalSt_ps_a2_S1
  ```
- a geotiff in a folder

  ```
  Z:\WUR\GasDrive_Thesis\ArcGIS\Application\FocalSt_ps_a2_S1.tif
  ```